# how to add new object to the existing dynamic response using angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm getting this dynamic response from the server . and here i want to push my mapD data into mapData (i.e Dynamic Data);

```
[
      {
        Name: "Aura",
        OrderState: "2",
        latitude: "28.197619999999997",
        longitude: "65.24778333333334"
      }
    ]
```

I store the above dynamic response as this.mapData = res.Data .

I have a static data too e.g.

```
public mapD:any=[{
    Name: "mad",
    OrderState: "2",
    latitude: "39.6868",
    longitude: "83.2185"
    }]
```

I want this above static object to contain the dynamic object so that I will get 2 objects in total - I'm using push method but unable to get the data using

`this.mapD.push(this.mapData)`

and im using `mapData` for saving the response and looping it in the template

Comment: `I will get 2 objects in total`  - you mean two objects in the mapD array?

Comment: Let newArr = [...firstArray, ...secondArray];

Comment: @mplungjan no in mapData

Comment: You received an Array. If the array always has only a uniqe element you must do this.mapD.pus(this.mapData[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot push an array into another. Use `spread` instead:

```
this.mapD.push(...this.mapData);
```

Or array.concat if you cannot use ES6:

```
this.mapD = this.mapD.concat(this.mapData);
```

Comment: by using spread operator im getting this below error --Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined--   im using mapData for saving the response and looping it in the templatethis.mapData

Comment: Initialize your map data like this.mapData=[];

Comment: you can use safe call like this `this.mapD.push(...(this.mapData || []));`

Answer (score 0):

You could declare `mapD` as an array of `mapData` so you could later access you object properties. A simple example:

```
mapData: Array<any>
mapD: Array<any>

getResponse() {
   this.yourApiService.subscribe(
      (response: Array<any>) => {
          this.mapDdata = response;
          // Loop through the response array here or push first item
          this.mapD.push(reponse[0]);
      }
   );
}
```

Now you have `mapD` which is of type array and contains your mapped `mapData` objects. This allows you to access the properties of the objects stored on that array.

Comment: im storing my respose in mapData

Comment: I have updated the above to add your response under mapData. If you wish to append the response into your static array you should push it right after the response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you mean, but if you want to merge the returned array `mapData` into the existing one `mapD`, you could try the following:

```
Array.prototype.push.apply(this.mapD, this.mapData);
```

It will store the result in `this.mapD`.

Hope this helps,